# How to assign a image From Form1 to Form2 Picturebox

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I am creating Image editor using C# Windows application, and now I have problem to assign a image to Form2 picturebox from Form1.

I am trying shown below code
The below code is written in Form1.cs page

```
    if(flag==0)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2(glb_image_list_arr[0]);
        f2.Show();                
    }
```

And the below code is written in Form2.cs page

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public Form2(Image img)
{
    this.Show();
    this.pictureBox1.Image = img;
}
```

In the "**this.pictureBox1.Image = img;**" line, I got the following error "**An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `InitializeComponents()` method call in `Form2(Image img)` constructor use

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public Form2(Image img)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.pictureBox1.Image = img;
}
```

will work.